# ui.router changing state, but ui-view doesn't display anything?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Though the states are changing successfully, I can't get the ui-view to update:

#### HTML

```html
<a ui-sref="promo.foo">Foo state</a>
<a ui-sref="promo.bar">Bar state</a>

<div ui-view=""></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
    .state('promo', {
               url: "/",
               abstract: true
           })
    .state('promo.foo', {
               url: "promo/foo",
               template: "'<h3>Foo</h3>'",
               controller: function($scope) {
                   $scope.value = 'foo';
               }
           })
    .state('promo.bar', {
               url: "promo/bar",
               template: "'<h3>Bar</h3>'",
               controller: function($scope) {
                   $scope.value = 'bar';
               }
           })
```

#### [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/414qzVJ8vmHMhbdBg3Ni?p=preview) (with bootstrap styling)

I have also tried setting `ui-view` to equal specific states also; and to dynamically change its RHS from my `$scope`.

Comment: Try not giving `ui-view` a value. `<div ui-view></div>`

Comment: Tried that; no change. AFAIK `attr=""` is equiv to `attr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to create nested views, the home state should have a template with an ui-view-element in it.
Also you have both double and single quotes in the template

```
template: "'<h3>Foo</h3>'"
```

Is this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FvDjAvL6sg7Y2PUyNUNW?p=preview) what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Give your abstract state a template containing  inside which your sub states will render ...  eg http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Comment: Yeah, that's something I tried earlier in the night. It also didn't work. Can devise a test-case out of that one showing the issue when I get back in ~4 hours.

Comment: well i tried it the plunker link you provided its works